# Convert CSV to JSON in desired format using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, automation

I would like to collect some insights on getting below output from it's corresponding input, I  tried some code but couldn't get result I wanted. Would like to see the table getting converted to desirable format as I have to work with huge CSV in later stage. Any inputs are highly appreciated.

**Input:**

| Reference | mcc | Value | currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd1234 | 5300 | 134.09 | USD |
| abcd1235 | 5411 | 38.48 | USD |

**Code used:**

```
from csv import DictReader
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint
import json

with open('Test_bulk_transactions_data.csv') as csvfile:
    r = DictReader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r]

    group = []
    uniquekeys = []

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['reference'], r['mcc'])):
        group.append({
            "reference": k[0],
            "mcc": k[1],
            "amount": [{k:v for k, v in d.items() if k not in ['reference','mcc']} for d in list(g)]})
        uniquekeys.append(k)

print(json.dumps(group, indent = 3) + '}')
```

**Current Output**:

```
[
   {
      "reference": "abcd1234",
      "mcc": "5300",
      "amount": [
         {
            "value": "134.09",
            "currency": "USD"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "reference": "abcd1235",
      "mcc": "5411",
      "amount": [
         {
            "value": "38.48",
            "currency": "USD"
         }
      ]
   }
]}
```

**Desired Output**:

```
{
  "cardTransactions": [
    {
      "reference": "abcd1234",
      "mcc": "5300",
      "amount": {
        "value": 134.09,
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    },
    {
      "reference": "abcd1235",
      "mcc": "5411",
      "amount": {
        "value": 38.48,
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try `group = {"cardTransactions" : group}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to append everything into "cardTransactions" key, and  the value can be cast to float when created.

```
"amount": [{k: float(v) for k, v in d.items() if k not in ['reference','mcc']} for d in list(g)]})
```

```
group = [] to group = defaultdict(list)
and group['cardTransactions'].append(... code as usual ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

your desired output will not allow for multiple value/currency in a given transaction, so you don't need to use groupby at all.

The process could be like this:

```
data = { 'cardTransactions':
         [{ 'amount': {'value'   : float(d.pop('Value')),
                       'currency': d.pop('currency')}, 
             **d }
          for d in r ]}

print(json.dumps(data, indent = 3))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the insights, I'll try later today and shall let know if it works. :)